# Example of action of a Lie algebroid

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, lie-algebroids, lie-groupoids

I am studying the notions of Lie groupoids and algebroids. I am mainly interested in the specific case of Lie algebroids which are actually Lie algebra bundles over an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^k$.

The problem is that I can not figure out a sufficiently simple example of action of a Lie algebroid over a manifold. Is there any resource where I can find one of them or a simple one which can be presented in an answer here?